# How can I parse this information with DOM Parser or xpath?

Tags: html, parsing, dom, xpath

I want to get some data from the URL above, I would like to get all of the torrent names under the search query.

http://kickass.to/usearch/grand%20theft%20auto%20v%20category:ps3/

Currently I got this code, but it just gets the html source from page, it would be great if someone could help me with parsing all the torrent names from the source.

```
function get_web_page( $url )
{
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider",
CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
);

$ch      = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$content = curl_exec( $ch );
$err     = curl_errno( $ch );
$errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
$header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );

$header['errno']   = $err;
$header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
$header['content'] = $content;
return $header;
}

$data =  get_web_page('http://kickass.to/usearch/grand%20theft%20auto%20v%20category:ps3/');
print_r(htmlspecialchars($data['content']));
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the use of PHP a requirement?

If not, the following groovy script solves your problem:

```
@Grab('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.6')

import groovyx.net.http.*
import groovy.xml.*

def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://kickass.to/usearch/grand%20theft%20auto%20v%20category:ps3/')

def html = http.get(path: '')

html.'**'.findAll { it.@class == 'torrentname' }.each { torrentNameDiv ->
  def titleLink = torrentNameDiv.'*'.findAll { it.@class.text().contains('normalgrey') }?.getAt(0)
  def title = titleLink.'*'.findAll { it.name() == 'STRONG' && it.@class == 'red' }.join(' ')
  def info = titleLink[0].children().findAll { it instanceof String }.join(' ')
  println "title=$title"
  println "info=$info"
}
```

Behind the scenes there are groovy classes like HTTPBuilder, XmlSlurper and GPathResult. The navigation over HTML structure is done via GPathResult.

Documentation here:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html

http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/home.html

Example here:

http://binarybuffer.com/2012/05/parsing-html-pages-like-a-boss-with-groovy

Answer (score 0):

Unless the html document is xhtml, it is probably not well-formed XML and you'll need an HTML parser rather than an XML parser... or you'll need to preprocess it into xhtml using something like the W3C's "tidy" tool, and then parse it as XML.

Once you get it into a standard W3C DOM, check whether that DOM implementation provides an implementation of XPath. If not, off-the-shelf implementations of XPath that run against user-provided DOMs are also available -- Apache Xalan is one obvious example. Xalan also implements XSLT, so you could combine gathering the data and arranging it into your desired format into a single stylesheet and avoid having to hand-code some of that.